# Ionic, back button disappears (history is null) on list details in tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a very simple app with 2 tabs, each containing a list with a detail view per list item. 
It's based on the default tabs template that ionic provides.
My problem is that the "back" button on a list item's detail view disappears sometimes.

index.html:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

tabs.html:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
  <ion-tab title="Offers-tab" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/offers">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-offers"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="Shops-tab" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/shops">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-shops"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

app.js config method:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
{
  $stateProvider
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
  .state('tab.offers',
  {
    url: '/offers',
    views:
    {
      'tab-offers':
      {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-offers.html',
        controller: 'OffersCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.offer-details',
  {
    url: '/offers/:offerID',
    views:
    {
      'tab-offers':
      {
        templateUrl: 'templates/offer-details.html',
        controller: 'OfferDetailsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.shops',
  {
    url: '/shops',
    views:
    {
      'tab-shops':
      {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-shops.html',
        controller: 'ShopsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.shop-details',
  {
    url: '/shops/:shopid',
    views:
    {
      'tab-shops':
      {
        templateUrl: 'templates/shop-details.html',
        controller: 'ShopDetailsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/offers');

});
```

services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Offers', function()
{
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var offers =
  [ { id: 0
     ,title: "Offer #0"
     ,description: "I'm the offer's description"
    }
  ];

  return {
    all: function()
    {
      return offers;
    }
   ,get: function(offerID)
    {
      console.log("offerID:" + offerID);
      for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++)
      {
        if (offers[i].id === parseInt(offerID))
        {
          return offers[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
})

.factory('Shops', function()
{
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var shops =
  [ { id: 0
     ,title: "Shop #0"
     ,description: "I'm the shop's description"
    }
  ];

  return {
    all: function()
    {
      return shops;
    }
   ,get: function(shopid)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < shops.length; i++)
      {
        if (shops[i].id === parseInt(shopid))
        {
          return shops[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

controller.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('OffersCtrl', function($scope, Offers) {
  $scope.offers = Offers.all();
})

.controller('OfferDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Offers) {
  $scope.offer = Offers.get($stateParams.offerID);
})

.controller('ShopsCtrl', function($scope, Shops){
  $scope.shops = Shops.all();
})

.controller('ShopDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Shops) {
  $scope.shop = Shops.get($stateParams.shopid);
});
```

To reproduce the "back button disappears" behaviour:

1. tap the "offer #0" item in the list on the "offers" tab. The "offer details" are shown, with a back button
2. switch to the "shops" tab
3. tap the "shop #0" item. The "shop details" view is shown. Now use the back button to return to the "shops" view
4. Switch to the "offers" tab, where the "offer details" view is still open. Click the "back button"
5. Now switch to the "shops" tab again, tap the "shop #0" item to open the shop details view: there is no back button anymore

When I check the $ionicHistory backView() method when it happens, I get a null (so that explains why the back button is gone, but I just can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a null...)

I am a complete newbie, so please forgive me if my question is unclear or my code is buggy, but I would really appreciate any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Try changing `'tab.offer-details'` to `tab.offers.details` and `tab.shop-deatils` to `tab.shops.details` and let me know if that fixes it....

Comment: Do you mean in app.js, so
.state('tab.offer-details
-> .state('tab.offers.details'
If so: doesn't work. Now I can't tap on a list item: nothing happens and no console errors

Answer (score 0):

So you should be able to change your

```
.state('tab.shop-details', {
    url: '/shops/:shopid',
    views: {
     'tab-shops': {
       templateUrl: 'templates/shop-details.html',
       controller: 'ShopDetailsCtrl'
     }
   }
})
```

to

```
.state('tab.shops.details', {
    url: '/shops/:shopid',
    views: {
     'tab-shops@tab': {
       templateUrl: 'templates/shop-details.html',
       controller: 'ShopDetailsCtrl'
     }
   }
})
```

and follow the same logic for your `.state('offer-details', ...)`

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOzezp?editors=1010)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get this to work. When I make your suggested changes I can't get tapping on a list item to work anymore: nothing happens. No errors. It looks like when I tap .otherwise('/tab/offers') is used

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the same behaviour on a codepen example:
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz
1. On the "home" tab, click the "scientific facts" button.
2. Switch to the "about" tab
3. In the about tab, click the "tabs nav stack" button.
4. The "tabs" image is shown, but note that there's a "< about" button. Click it
5. Switch back to the "home" tab. There the "banging your head.." view is still shown, with a "< home" button. Click this button to go back.
7. Now switch to the "About" tab again and click the "tabs nav stack" button again: the back button ("< about") is gone.

Comment: There you go all working [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOzezp?editors=1010). You just needed to think about the url `href` on your `<a>` because you add to the url as you go deeper into the history stack.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you are saying. I do know now that the initial problem (the back-button disappearing) is a bug in Ionic, they've confirmed that. As for the code-changes you propose: as I said, I've tried those, but I don't know if that's a workaround for my initial problem, because I can't get it to work. If I make these changes then I can't even tap on a list item anymore. That has probably a lot to do with me being new to angular :-)

Comment: If you mean the example code here above: yes of course. I can't get that to work. Just copying/pasting your example code does not work, because if I do that I can't tap on a list item anymore: nothing happens, as I said before.  So I can't confirm nor deny it's a solution for the initial problem, which is a confirmed bug in ionic.

Comment: [Have a look at this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOzezp?editors=1010) obviously you will have to look at the hrefs in you HTML templates as changing the routes in your JS inevitably means you have to change the URLs.

Comment: Obviously. But if you follow my steps, as mentioned above (comment from May 19th, where I mention this codepen), you will see the exact problem. I'm very sorry, but I'm feeling we are walking in circles here.